# How to use response of a axio call to build request of another

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios, nuxt.js

This is how my current `asyncData` looks like, it's working and filling `events` and `booking` using axios calls

```
async asyncData({ params, app }) {
  const events = await app.$api.event.index(app.i18n.locale)
  const booking = await app.$api.event.getByPath(
    app.i18n.locale,
    params.detail
  )

  return {
    events,
    booking
  }
},
```

But i need to add another object into data, `registration`, which needs a `booking` value to generate the axios url.

I tried in the `booking`'s promise

```
async asyncData({ params, app }) {
  let registration;
  const events = await app.$api.event.index(app.i18n.locale)
  const booking = await app.$api.event.getByPath(
    app.i18n.locale,
    params.detail

  ) .then((result) => {
        registration = app.$api.event.getRegitrations(
          app.i18n.locale,
          result.id
        )
  });

  return {
    events,
    booking,
    registration
  }
},
```

But this way `booking` is empty and `registration` has value `[object Promise]` (even that i see both axios responses in the dev tools)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define `registration` as data property then watch `booking` property and update `registration` when `booking` is available

```
data(){
   return{
    registration:null
  }
},
watch:{
   booking:{
    handler(newVal){
      if(newVal && newVal.id){
         this.$api.event.getRegitrations(
          this.i18n.locale,// or this.$i18n
          newVal.id
        ).then(res=>{
          this.registration=res.data
       })
     }
   },
  deep:true,
  immediate:true
 }
},
async asyncData({ params, app }) {

  const events = await app.$api.event.index(app.i18n.locale)
  const booking = await app.$api.event.getByPath(
    app.i18n.locale,
    params.detail

  ) 
 
  return {
    events,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what are you using it for the http calling but,
If you use `axios`, you can get a data like this.

```
  const booking = await app.$api.event.getByPath(
    app.i18n.locale,
    params.detail

  ) .then((response) => {
        registration = app.$api.event.getRegitrations(
          app.i18n.locale,
          response.data.id
        )
  });
```

Comment: Hello Ian thanks, i don't think the problem is with the axios calls because i see the correct values in the dev tools, but the variables are empty

Comment: Ah, okay. I misunderstood your question. you'd better use vuex in this case. Store it your registration data in "Store" and "Get" on your front side.

Comment: Because your code is asynchronous working.

Answer (score 1):

An await call is a promise that gets resolved first before executing the rest of the async function code. So you already have access to the result of the variable `events` before you try to assign to `booking`. If you `await` for `booking`, you can read from the variable and use it to compose the next Axios call.

```
async asyncData({ params, app }) {
  const events = await app.$api.event.index(app.i18n.locale);
  const booking = await app.$api.event.getByPath(
    app.i18n.locale,
    params.detail
  );
  const registration = await app.$api.event.getRegitrations(
    app.i18n.locale,
    booking.id
  )

  return {
    events,
    booking,
    registration
  }
}
```